# my projects in intellij ultimate are no longer recognizing the annotations

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, sdk, project, program-entry-point

i lately updated intellih ultimate fron 2019 to 2020.2 version
and all the projects i create with springboot initializer are not recognizing the most important annotations such as @SpringBootApplication
also it does not recognise the main classes in my old projects !
example

```
Erreur : impossible de trouver ou charger la classe principale com.esi.msformation.MsFormationApplication
```

the sdk is up to date
i unistall it and install again
nothing changed
so any help ?

Comment: Does it happen on compilation or only in the editor? Do you see the dependencies imported into modules? Any errors in [the logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085)?

Comment: yes in happens on compilation , the dependencies are not imported and no problem in the log

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Zip and share the project folder and the IDE logs.

Comment: when i run i got this error ` Erreur : impossible de trouver ou charger la classe principale com.esi.msformation.MsRegistryApplication`

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code , bcz i download it from git , it is an installation prblm i believe

Comment: Please edit your Question to include clarifications. Do not add those in comments.